# How to align a part of the header to the right, with the help of Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to find a solution,  but nothing worked in the way I wanted. I’m starting with Bootstrap and I might have missed something.

Currently, I have the following code (sample code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Pmilan/441u5763/)) which worked likede this

Header for big screens

```
|[   Website name  ]                  |
|                            [log off]|
|                       [[ lan1ang2 ]]|
```

Header for mobile screens

```
|[   Website name  ]                    |
|                              [log off]|
|                   [[ lang1 ][ lang2 ]]|
```

---

I want the header for big screens to look like this:

```
|[   Website name  ]           [ log off ]|
|                     [[ lang1 ][ lang2 ]]|
```

And the header for mobile screens should be like this:

```
|[   Website name  ]             |
|[[ lang1 ][ lang2 ]]   [log off]|
```

Thanks for any hint or answers.

Comment: share you current code

Comment: It is in link "here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dabble a bit more in to the [Grid Template for Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) to see what happens when your screen is small `col-xs-X` (mobile), medium `col-md-X` (tablet) or large `col-lg-X` (desktop). You only set up a grid for the desktop, but what if the user is on his mobile?

A better way to approach this is a *mobile first* approach, so you can expand your canvas (as a website is just a painting) and be more in control of what's happening on your page.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ok8sy6k4/1/) to see what you wanted.

To get what you want, the items should be display with the same length on mobile (hence the equal `col-xs-12` for left area and right area). Notice the difference on tablet: `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`. I hope this will get you started to learn more about grid templating in Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. That is almost OK.
Do you have an idea, why language part do not align (text) to the right side like login part?
https://jsfiddle.net/Pmilan/441u5763/7/

Comment: @P.Milan Because you put English and Deutsch in `.col-sm-3`, they're stuk in there. Remove them and use for example a list, see this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f86wmtxv/

Comment: OK, I could do this before. I want to ask are there the solution in bootstrap. Obviously not. Thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions: you can try to make it all work in only one `row`-div and different `col-push`s and `col-pull`s for different sizes.
Since this might get really messy, I recommend just using `visible`

```
<div class="col-sm-6 namesite">
    <h1><a href="/">My website</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 logoff visible-sm visible-lg">
    <a href="/" class="pull-right">logoff</a>
</div>
...
<div class="row visible-xs">
      <section id="login" class="pur">...
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkzfkggn/